# How can I run a kernel prior to 2.0?

Tags: kernel, release-management

I am working on a project i.e. trying to adapt Linux kernel for scalable multi core architecture where no. of cores are increasing day by day.

For my project I want a Linux distribution like Ubuntu having Linux kernel before 2.0 release i.e. it may be Ubuntu having linux kernel 1.3 release, where can I get this, if possible please try to help me as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu was first released in 2004 and so never with a kernel older than 2.0.